# I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and I can not connect to the network

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04, dell, inspiron

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my Dell Inspiron 1501. Now I have no network capability. I had the same problem with 12.04. Ubuntu 11.10 only recognised my wired network, but not WiFi. What can I do to fix this? I am sending this message from my phone.

Comment: you don't have wired access either? not even if you restart with the cable in?

Comment: I have unplugged and replugged and restarted in various combinations.

Comment: ok try running sudo dhclient -r; sudo dhclient eth0    substitute the name of your wired network interface, cable in. if not please copy what it says in your /etc/network/interfaces  file into the question.

Comment: Substitute the name where?

Comment: # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

Comment: Auto lo    Iface lo inet loopback

Comment: the problem seems to be it cannot find either of your network cards in devices. please say what comes up if you run ifconfig. as if it shows in ifconfig it can be added to the interfaces file

Comment: Lo.  Link encap:local loopback   Inet addr:127.0.0.1. Mask:250.0.0.0. Inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host. UP LOOPBACK RUNNING. MTU:65536. Metric:1. RX packets:608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0. TX packets:608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 collisions:0 txqueuelen:0. RX bytes 49936 (49.9 KB) TX bytes 49936 (40.9 KB)

Comment: Sorry bout the jumbled appearance. Phones arent god for this

Comment: oh no its fine. Ok so the drivers are almost certainly not there so  you will need to install the drivers from Nicks answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a second computer, try installing the wireless drivers, that could perhaps solve it. if you have a wireless switch, try turning it on and off again.

Comment: No 2nd computer. No switch.

Comment: what kind of pc are you running, i might be able to send you the drivers, like model number

Comment: Dell inspiron 1501

Comment: Can you download files on your phone?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to download all the newwork drivers for you, aswell as how to install them, so i can email them to you, you put them on your phone, and then copy them onto your computer

Comment: Lets give it a shot. Email them.

Comment: I need an email address.

Comment: Seanwho@icloud.com

Comment: I've sent the drivers in a .zip file, hopefully this works

Comment: I have the files on my computer. Cant get to the directory in order to install

Comment: I swore i could just right click and run in terminal

Comment: sudo apt-get install ndisgtk, i don't think this will work, since you have no internet, but you can try, p.s, do you have wine?

Comment: That didnt work. I just need to get to the directory in terminal. The directory is  home/documents/untitledfolder/ndiswrapper-1.58

Comment: cd your way into it

Comment: I have been trying. I dont think i'm doung it right.  Cd /home/documents/untitledfolder/ndiswrapper-1.58/

Comment: I don't know, i rarely cd in, you may need to look it up on google on your phone.

Comment: Okay, got in, got ndiswrapper installed. Beyond that, these instructions included are not helpful. All i need to do now is install the drivers.

Comment: I found the broadcom driver, but it keeps having errors tryig to open in archive manager. What does this ndiswrapper program do?

Comment: Following these instructions doesnt get me anything but errors. Apparently ubuntu should have already had these drivers available when i installed. I told it to install proprietary drivers. I have the drivers, but no way to install them.

Comment: ndiswrapper installs xp drivers, and your those drivers are not native to linux, so you need to install them from ndiswrapper